# traceroute / mtr from multiple locations, How can we do it ? (Or alternate way)

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, traceroute

I have a website, recently due to some network issue, Most of my customers are reporting slow loading time of my website.

When I reported this to my DataCenter, they are asking me to send the ping / tracert results from various IPs, Which is very difficult to do it. If 100s of customers are visiting my website for buying, I can not ask them to send the tracert to use my website. That is impossible.

We have changed the web application in such a way that, We are able to capture the website's loading time & client's IP.

```
date /            loading time   IP    location
30 04:59:51 - 1.785 - xx0.61.30.xxx Mumbai
30 05:00:29 - 3.218 - xx4.79.168.xxx null
30 05:00:37 - 54.399 - xx2.41.204.xxx null ====> Loadtime is high 
30 05:03:05 - 3.153 - xx2.174.249.xxx Chennai
30 05:03:48 - 70.231 - xx2.41.204.xx null   ====> Loadtime is high
30 05:04:01 - 3.911 - x.22.89.xx Bhandup
30 05:04:34 - 1.282 - xx2.174.xx.221 Chennai
30 05:05:17 - 2.837 - xx.177.xx4.196 Delhi
30 05:05:31 - 1.354 - xx2.177.xx4.196 Delhi
30 05:05:55 - 4.177 - xx2.167.xx.87 Bangalore
30 05:06:49 - 7.265 - xx.96.xx.180 null
30 05:06:55 - 5.539 - xx7.xx.65.19 Bangalore
30 05:08:05 - 1.465 - xx3.x3.50.82 null
30 05:08:26 - 1.822 - xx2.xx6.58.195 null
30 05:09:10 - 0.757 - xx2.xx.58.195 null
30 05:10:23 - 5.865 - xx6.xx.136.220 Bangalore
```

Now, How can I find the solution to this problem ?

If I do a traceroute to the slow loading IP address from my server, there are some problem noticied in mtr or traceroute. Will it help in resolving the issue by my DataCenter ?

Comment: There are third-party services that will monitor your site from many locations, and send reports to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could rent some cheap VPS servers that are positioned around the world and run traceroute yourself from those servers back to your website. AWS allows you rent per minute.

Another option would be to search for "traceroute online" there are a large number of websites that allow you to run a traceroute from a remote server.

Examples:

http://traceroute-online.com

http://ping.eu/traceroute/

Of course you will need to find these servers in different parts of the world for a comprehensive test.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool https://perfops.net/cli to run multiple network tests including traceroute from 200+ locations. It includes free tests.