# Can I do reverse traceroute?

Tags: troubleshooting, traceroute

Is it possible to do reverse traceroute ?
This is very important for me to know, Why the websites are loading slow for my clients in certain area ?

I have explained my problem here: (why  i need reverse traceroute)

[traceroute / mtr from multiple locations, How can we do it ? (Or alternate way)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181991/traceroute-mtr-from-multiple-locations-how-can-we-do-it-or-alternate-way)

Comment: @Bratchley Usually *the path* is NOT *the path*! In fact, in most cases on the public Internet, unless you are tracing within the network of a single ISP (and often even if you are), the path in the reverse direction will be quite different. This is because of things like hot potato routing.

Comment: Due to various reasons the route TCP traffic will take from A -> B is not necessarily the same as the route from B -> A and a reverse traceroute is not possible. Your best bet is a somewhat savvy client that can use developer tools to get performance timings such as DNS and page load times as well as ping latency etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built-in to IP that lets you do a reverse traceroute, that is, a traceroute from some remote server back to you. That is why network administrators often set up public looking glasses for other network administrators to use. These looking glasses were historically `telnet`-based interfaces but nowadays are usually available through web servers. They typically allow traceroute and BGP routing table lookups from the perspective of the network that hosts the looking glass. Large ISPs often host multiple looking glasses installed on (geographically, topologically) different parts of their network.

Starting point for finding looking glasses that allow traceroute: [traceroute.org](http://www.traceroute.org/)